# Question about points in the $0$ dimensional closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec}R[X_1, ..., X_n]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $V(J)$ be an irreducible closed subset of $\operatorname{Spec}R[X_1, ..., X_n]$ of dimension $t$. We suppose $R$ is an integral domain with algebraically closed fraction field $K$.

I am wondering about the following. Can we always find $t+1$ linear forms $L_1, ..., L_{t+1}$ with coefficients in $R$ and they are linearly independent over $K$ such that

1. The dimension of $V(J) \cap V(L_1) \cap ... \cap V(L_j)$ is $t-j$
2. $V(J) \cap V(L_1) \cap ... \cap V(L_{t+1})$ is the empty set.

Thank you

Edit. The question has been modified based on the commment

Comment: Without further conditions on $V(J)$, your assertion 1 is incorrect. For instance, if $R=\Bbb C$, $n=2$, $J=(x_1)$, and $L_1=x_1$, you get that your intersection is 1-dimensional. Even in the case where your assertion 1 is correct, assertion 2 is false: consider $R=\Bbb Z$, $n=1$, $J=(2)$, and $L_1=x_1$, which gives a single $\Bbb F_2$-point, which is not a closed point of any affine space over $\Bbb Q=\operatorname{Frac} \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Dear Johnny, do you plan to revise your question, or should I turn my comment in to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Clearly there can only be $n$ linearly independent forms in $R[X_1,\cdots,X_n]$ over $K$, so if $t+1>n$ we are out of luck and the claim must be false. Such an example may happen if $R$ is positive-dimensional.

For instance, let $R$ be the ring of algebraic integers (the integral closure of $\Bbb Z$ inside $\overline{\Bbb Q}$). Then $R$ is an integral domain with algebraically closed fraction field and  $R$ has dimension one, as integral ring extensions preserve dimension. Now consider $V(0) \subset \Bbb A^1_R$: it is of dimension two, but one cannot find three linearly independent linear forms in $R[X]$.

(An aside: it seems possible to me that this question may be an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), wherein you're asking about your attempted solution rather than your underlying problem. If this is the case, you may find better help with your underlying issue if you ask a question about your underlying issue and add enough context.)

Comment: Yes, you are right.... I have been trying to figure out the details of this result https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355269/specialization-of-z-subset-mathbbpn-k-with-respect-to-a-valuation-ring-r and this was one of my attempts at it